# Stripe webhook details always coming empty

Tags: php, yii, stripe-payments, webhooks

```
public function actionStripeHook() {
    $this->layout = '//layouts/empty';
    try {
            Stripe::setApiKey(Yii::app() - > params['secret_key']);
            $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
            $event = json_decode($postdata);
            $input = @file_get_contents("php://input");
            var_dump($input);
            $event_json = json_decode($input);
    }
}
```

In Stripe Webhook set this Url,But in this response i got always empty whats wrong in my code.

Comment: What does var_dump($event) return?

Comment: I am checking its value coming or not ? but that json value coming empty

Comment: How are you debugging $event & $event_json? Yii::log()?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the note on this page:

http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

You will see that in many versions of PHP php://input can only be read once, and will be empty the second time it is read.  If you look closely at your code you will notice that you are reading php://input twice.  Make sure and only read it once.  That is probably your problem.